# Get meeting recorded from Microsoft stream API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-teams

We have a calling & meeting bot,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview
which records the call in teams. We want to fetch the recorded video.The recorded meeting in teams call, stored in Microsoft stream.
Do we have any API to fetch the recorded video from Microsoft stream.

Comment: according to Microsoft its on a roadmap for q4 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=25197

Comment: Thanks for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to get the meeting recording through an API. This is something we have in our backlog but we do not have an ETA on when this will be available.

Comment: Any news about this issue?